# Getting false for a true statement

Tags: python, floating-point, int

In the below code, when the inputs to a,b and c are 2,3 and 4 respectively,

```
a=input('Enter length of first side of triangle: ')
b=input('Enter length of second side of triangle: ')
c=input('Enter length of third side of triangle: ')
print((a+b)>c)
```

The output is

```
False
```

But if the inputs are changed to float (as depicted below),

```
a=float(input('Enter length of first side of triangle: '))
b=float(input('Enter length of second side of triangle: '))
c=float(input('Enter length of third side of triangle: '))
print((a+b)>c)
```

then the output is

```
True
```

Please explain why this is happening

Comment: You are comparing `str` in your first snippet.

Comment: Convert to `int` and then compare.

Comment: `input` returns a string representing the sequence of characters entered, not an int representing the numeric value of the input parsed as a base-10 integer, even if the input happens to be parseable as such. String `+` and `>` don't work by numeric value.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I read inputs as numbers?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20449427/how-can-i-read-inputs-as-numbers)

Comment: @SrinivasGadepalli Consider accpeting an answer that helped you understand: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work

Answer (score 4):

Result of your first snippet is:

```
('2' + '3') > '4'
# which is equivalent to:
'23' > '4'
```

In python, strings are compared based on their unicode value, one character at the time. Thus the above comparison becomes:

```
ord('2') > ord('4')
# which is equivalent to
50 > 52
```

which is `False`.

On the other hand, your second snippet is a simple `float` comparison:

```
(2.0 + 3.0) > 4.0
```

which is `True`

Answer (score 2):

Previously:

```
a=input('Enter length of first side of triangle: ')   #  '2'
b=input('Enter length of second side of triangle: ')  #  '3'
c=input('Enter length of third side of triangle: ')   #  '4' 
print((a+b)>c)   # ('2' + '3') > '4' becoming '23' > '4'
```

`input` returns a `str`, Convert it to `int` and then compare:

```
a=int(input('Enter length of first side of triangle: '))    # 2
b=int(input('Enter length of second side of triangle: '))   # 3
c=int(input('Enter length of third side of triangle: '))    # 4
print((a+b)>c)    # (2 + 3) > 4   becoming 5 > 4
```

Answer (score 1):

How about converting the input which is `string` to `int`

```
a=int(input('Enter length of first side of triangle: '))
b=int(input('Enter length of second side of triangle: '))
c=int(input('Enter length of third side of triangle: '))
print((a+b)>c)
```

This gives

```
Enter length of first side of triangle: 2
Enter length of second side of triangle: 3
Enter length of third side of triangle: 4
True
```

Answer (score 1):

The input function returns the string value & you are comparing the string values not the integers.

Please type-cast the input values to integer by following piece of code .

```
a=int(input('Enter length of first side of triangle: '))
b=int(input('Enter length of second side of triangle: '))
c=int(input('Enter length of third side of triangle: '))
print((a+b)>c)
```

or

```
a=input('Enter length of first side of triangle: ')
b=input('Enter length of second side of triangle: ')
c=input('Enter length of third side of triangle: ')
print((int(a)+int(b))>int(c))
```

Answer (score 0):

The return type of input() is string. So when you are doing `('1'+'2')` as string the output is `12`.

So you would need to convert the string to numeric datatype using `int()`  or `float()` and that would work.